# how to distribute all image with poper tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i try to create multiple image array and now i want to add proper tag with specific deck like(Hearts,Diamonds,Spades,Clubs). so in image name as C=dimond, R=Heart,K=spades,F=Clubs and image no as 11=Jack,12=Queen,13=King...so how to distribute it with proper tag so i can indentify specific image.

->>>>>>>>

```
    imagearr = 
             [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C1.png"],

            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C2.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C3.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C4.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C5.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C6.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C7.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C8.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C9.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C10.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C11.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C12.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"C13.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F1.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F2.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F3.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F4.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F5.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F6.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F7.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F8.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F9.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F10.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F11.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F12.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"F13.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K1.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K2.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K3.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K4.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K5.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K6.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K7.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K8.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K9.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K10.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K11.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"k12.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"K13.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R1.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R2.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R3.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R4.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R5.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R6.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R7.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R8.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R9.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R10.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R11.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R12.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"R13.png"],nil];
```

..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better work around this issue rather than taking a bunch of images in the array. Initialize an Enum with all different deck categories and loading the image through dynamically generated name for e.g:

```
// In a header file
typedef enum {
  HEARTS,       // Hearts
  DIAMONDS,   // Diamonds
  SPADES,       // Spades
  CLUBS       // Club
} DeckType;

// In a source file
NSString * const DeckType_toString[] = {
  @"H",
  @"D",
  @"S",
  @"C"
};

- (UIImage *)getDeckImage:(DeckType)deckType withCardNo:(NSInteger)cardNo {

    return [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", DeckType_toString[deckType], cardNo]];
}
```

You can also take another enum with group of 1...13 cards and used them instead of `cardNo`

Comment: hi i try it and i set tag for each imageview but still i can't identify the imageview at touch event. thanks for your suggestion and i got solution for arranging array because of you....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,you could create a `UIImage` with `tag` .because it's inherited from `NSObject` **NOT** `UIView` which provide you an integer tag variable and used by the `UIView` class.

But still you could do it by writing a wrapper for you `UIView` class, and should be like below

**use below as reference.**

```
@interface MyUIImageWrapper: NSObject
{
  UIImage* iMyImage;
  int tag;
}
```

you could have some init function which take two argument one for image name and others for tag value

Like below

```
-(id) initWithTag:(NSString*) fileName withTag:(int) myTag ;
```

And the implementation for the  method.

```
-(id) initWithTag:(NSString*) fileName withTag:(int) myTag
{
         if(self = [super init])
         {
           iMyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
           tag = myTag;
         }
        return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify images in a collection I'm suggesting an NSDictionary instead of an NSArray so every image is associated with an NSString, e.g. [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:..., [UIImage imageNamed:@"R7.png"], @"R7", ...]; tagging works for UIImageViews (all UIView descendants) and is more proper for retrieving already added subviews...

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but i set some images on imageview and place it to the different positions and now i want to identify touch image will move to the center of screen with animation.....

Comment: If you're asking how to do that's a different question i suppose, there are many ways to do it, one is to identify which view is the tap on and move it with touchesMoved